# Fortifyclient command to create version

Tags: fortify

I have Fortify SCA on my machine and i am trying to create a version in a project using command line.

Can anyone tell me fortifyclient command to create version in a project.

Answer (score 1):

The API of SSC version 3.60 does not support project creation. You can only do it with GUI.